# How to ensure that multiple rows get batched during parallelization?

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to parallelize the code on the FastGTN GitHub repo using DataLoader: https://github.com/seongjunyun/Graph_Transformer_Networks

Unfortunately, this breaks line 205 in model_fastgtn.py. Before parallelization, the tensors were of size:

```
total_edge_index shape: torch.Size([2, 32292])
edge_index shape: torch.Size([2, 32292])
```

After parallelization, the tensors are of size:

```
total_edge_index shape: torch.Size([1, 32292])
edge_index shape: torch.Size([1, 32292])
```

How to prevent the batching from changing the number of rows?

I created a Dataset class and used DataLoader:

```
train_dataset = GraphDataset(train_node, train_target)
    valid_dataset = GraphDataset(valid_node, valid_target)
    test_dataset = GraphDataset(test_node, test_target)

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
    valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

I also tried using a custom DataLoader:

```
class CustomBatchSampler(BatchSampler):
    def __init__(self, sampler, batch_size, drop_last):
        super().__init__(sampler, batch_size, drop_last)

    def __iter__(self):
        batch = []
        last_idx = None
        for idx in self.sampler:
            last_idx = idx
            batch.append(idx)
            if len(batch) == self.batch_size:
                yield batch
                batch = []
        if last_idx is not None and len(batch) == 1:
            batch.append(last_idx)
            yield batch
```

None of this is making a difference. Not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: I see you used a batch_size of 1. The first dim is generally the batch dim. I think you need to transpose the edge_index before batching.